# filter is not setting state as intended, how do i create async if statement?

Tags: react-native, filter, state

I'm fetching data from my backend and storing it as a state. Inputs from local storage are then supposed to be filtering the backend data and rendering the results. However it seems my .filter isn't setting state as anything (undefined). However, if i save my code after a duration of time it then operates as intended until i refresh.

What is happening, do i need to create a async statement?

````
import "./Home.css";
import axios from 'axios';

const Tables = () => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isloading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [result, setResult] = useState();


    const test = async () => {
      
      await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/').then((res)=>{
      setData(res.data.data)
      setIsLoading(false)

    })

    const storedSize = localStorage.getItem('size');
    const storedFeel = localStorage.getItem('feel');
    const storedCost = localStorage.getItem('cost');
    const storedStyle = localStorage.getItem('style');
    const storedRoom = localStorage.getItem('room');


    const info = {size: storedSize, feel: storedFeel, cost: storedCost, style: storedStyle, room: storedRoom};

    const keys = Object.keys(info);
    const values = Object.values(info);

    
      const x = values;
      const type = keys;

      if(type[3]==="style") {

        const filterProcess = data?.filter( i => {
        return i.style===x[3];

      })

      setResult(filterProcess)
    
    };
      
    };

    useEffect(() => {

      test();
  
    }, []);



  
  if (isloading){
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>
  };



  const clear = () => {

    window.location = '/First'; 
    localStorage.clear();
    
  };

  const renderTable = () => {
  
    return result?.map((hero)=>{
      return (
    <div className="card mx-2" style={{width: '18rem'}} key={hero.data_id}>
    <img className="card-img-top" src={hero.image} alt="Card image cap"/>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h5 className="card-title">{hero.name}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">Feel: {hero.feel}</p>
      <p className="card-text">Style: {hero.style}</p>
      <p className="card-text">Cost: £{hero.cost}</p>
      <p className="card-text">Room: {hero.room}</p>
      <p className="card-text">Size: {hero.size}</p>

      <a href={hero.web_link} target="_blank" className="btn btn-primary">Go to link</a>
      <br/>
    </div>
    </div>
    )

    })
    
  
  };
    return (
      <Fragment>
      
        {renderTable()}

        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={clear}>New Search</button>

  
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
  

export default Tables;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! - I moved my data state inside the useEffect dependencies.